# Reading C++ ofstream written file in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm writing out a file in C++ as:

```
void TestExportWriteOut()
{
    const auto filePath = R"(C:\TestOut.bin)";
    ofstream outFile(filePath, ios::out | ios::binary);
    outFile<< 1;
    outFile.flush();
    outFile.close();
}
```

and trying to read it in C# as:

```
[TestMethod]
public void LoadTestOut()
{
    const string filePath = "C:\\TestOut.bin";
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
    {
        var intOne = reader.ReadInt32(); //!!Throws Exception
        Assert.AreEqual(intOne, 1);
    }
}
```

However, right at the line where I try to read the integer value 1, I get an exception saying:

> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: 'Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.'

---

What's the correct way of reading files in C# that are created using `ofstream` in C++?

I can see the file created by C++ on the file system, and while all I wrote to it is an int, its size is 1KB.

Comment: Are you sure that `out << 1` writes 32 bit integer value? Open file with hex editor and check the bytes.

Comment: The `<<` operator writes text. The opening mode has no effect on whether data is writing as text or binary data.

Comment: @Reniuz: This is super unexpected.

Comment: @Darnold this is not what you do with binary data file.

Comment: @Reniuz my bad, i did not pay attention to the .bin or the ios::binary

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the calls to `outFile.flush();` and `outFile.close()`; aren't needed. The destructor will do both of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ios::binary` flags does not do what you think(*).  It doesn't influence the behavior of `operator<<(int)` which still put a text representation of its argument. On the C++ side, use `outFile.write()` to output the binary representation (in conjunction with the `ios::binary` flag).

---

(*) It does open the file as a binary file for OS which have a notion of binary file different of text file (neither Windows nor Unix are in that class) and it prevent the transformation of `\n` in the normal way of representing end of line for the OS (Windows use a pair of characters for that, that's why you need the `ios::binary` flag)

Comment: Windows *is* in that class which distinguishes text files from binary files.

Comment: @Eljay The text files of Windows are a strict subset of its binary files and there is no difference in its API between the two, only programs are making a difference in the way the content of the files are interpreted. The class I was speaking it the one of OS with several kinds of files, with different features and API to access them (see for instance the RMS subsystem of (Open)VMS with its, IIRC, 4 access methods and 4 record formats). Windows and Unix are not in that class, they only have streams with a (different) convention about how end of lines are represented in the stream.

Comment: Ahh, I see... the `ios::binary` affects the interpretation of the files on Windows.  Do you have a link to the RMS subsystem of (Open)VMS as used by C++, and how those different file modes are handled?  That sounds interesting; I'm not sure what to Google for since my attempts failed to prod Google to divulge some useful links.  I've only done a little work on DEC VMS, and that would have been in the 1980s.

Comment: @Eljay I'm sorry I've just memories of using C on VMS at about the same time frame as you and even then I was more a Unix guy than a VMS one.  IIRC, C streams, binary and text, were mapped to one of the access method and to the stream file format of RMS.  If you wanted something else, you used VMS API directly just as you can use the content of `<unistd.h>` or `<windows.h>` nowadays.

Comment: It's alright, and thanks for the info (and memories)!  I remember my VMS experience (in early C++) was where I learned that `$` could be used in identifiers, and every compiler I've ever used either allowed them or had a command-line flag to allow `$` as an identifier character.  I've found some info on OpenVMS, which appears to be making some sort of revival on the x86 platform. But no info regarding file modes yet, or how the C++ flag(s) maps to the underlying file system file formats.